# Date in arguments using i18n

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, date

I'm working on a nodeJs project in typescript

I use i18n npm package to manage text translation through all the application. For basic use it's ok.

My issue is with dates, here is the problem :

```
import * as i18n from 'i18n';
export const translate = (key: string, args = {}): string => {
    return i18n.__(key, args);
};

 Exemple : resultString = translate('You have an appointement with {{name}} on {{date}}', {
               name : 'Mr smith',
               date : '20/11/2019',
           });
```

=> resultString is `You have an appointement with Mr Smith on 20&#x2F;11&#x2F;2019`

The character `/` is converted to it's hex

Any idea why ?

EDIT -----

I tried using  `unescape()` on the final string but it's not working

Comment: Do you mean `ng-translate` or `ngx-translate` ?
Because `ng-translate` is quite old and not updated since 3 years and (if it is not yet deep bounded in your project) i suggest you to use `ngx-translate`.

Comment: Made the edit, it's `ngx-translate`

Comment: The problem is that Angular is sanitizing these values. Not ngx-translate. (check your console it has warnings). You could try to bypass html sanitizer

Comment: My bad i've missunderstood the issue, the pkg is `i18n` used on the backend side, Nodejs

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe is just a problem of how the translate service is been used. I try this way and i didn't have any issue:

component.html

```
{{'HOME.TEST' | translate:{name: msg.name, date: msg.date}  }}
<br>
{{translation()}}
```

component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  msg = {name : 'Mr smith', date : '20/11/2019'};

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'fr']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    const browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
  }


  translation() : string {
    return this.translate.instant('HOME.TEST', this.msg)
  }
}
```

I leave a link to stackbliz with a demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-translation-service-tc8tju